# Two Columns, need to match a string from one to another

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have two columns of Data.

Column A Contains cells (105k) path directories with filename

```
Column A
C:/Im/Not/GoodAt/excel.pdf
C:/Im/Not/GoodAt/exce1.pdf
C:/Im/Not/GoodAt/excez.pdf
C:/Im/Not/GoodAt/excef.pdf
```

Column B contains Just filenames (about 7k)

```
Column B
exce2.pdf
exce4.pdf
excel.pdf
excez.pdf
```

I need conditional formatting to highlight the entire cell in column A, if the string filename in column B exists within a cell in column A.

I've tried match and a few other tips with no avail.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$1:$B$4,A1))))
```

[image]

MATCH would not work as it would need to be a CSE array formula and CSE array formulas do not work in conditional formatting.

CSE array formulas being those formulas that need to be confirmed with **C**trl-**S**hift-**E**nter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode to force into array mode.

Comment: You may want to define "CSE" for those not familiar with array formulas.